# sql statement issue after url rewrite

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, url-rewriting

I am implementing URL REWRITE (IIS 7) in a client's website.

but I have a problem with the sql statement.

before I had this:

```
select * from 360 where titulo='"&request("titulo")&"'"
```

and it was ok.

an example of titulo was "Fiexpo Latinoamérica"

my old url was   portfolio.asp?titulo=Fiexpo Latinoamérica

but now my new url is   /portfolio/fiexpo-latinoamerica

I use ASP replace to remove the spaces and change them with an "-" among others simbols.

so now, my sql statement does not works... because there is no titulo in the database with that name.

how do I do?

I could easyle replace  the - with an space, ok but I have "tildes"    á é í ó ú

what do I do?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is that new URL generated?  You should save the new URL (slug) for every item in the database so you can use that to generate the links and to search it when somebody is requesting the page.

Comment: thank you Marco, I will create a second "titulo" field in the data base with the new format.